# Change structure with media query in CSS3

Tags: html, css

edit: added a link to jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/h280xb6p/

Im currently practicing responsive design. Whenever the browser window gets below 400px the structure of the content change.
I have this menu that I use the structure of `<a>`. What I need help with is to change the html code from `<a>` to `<option>` whenever someone with a max-width of 400px or lower enter the site.

I know it's possible to change the appearance, like CSS rules with media query, but is it possible to substitute html code with another html code?

Subject: #menu

```
@media (max-width:400px){
    section#box1, section#box2{
float: none;
width:100%; 

    }

    section#menu    {
        }
}
```

Comment: a jsfiddle here would be very beneficial.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h280xb6p/

Comment: Why do you want to change the html tags?

Comment: I want the menu to be a dropdown menu to smartphone users. I think that <option> is an outstanding code to accomplish what im after.

Comment: @Mello I see. Well you can't do that. You'll need to create two menu's and display/hide the correct ones at the correct state.

Comment: @ThomasBormans Oh, ah well then I shall!:) Thanks for answer and have a sweet day.

Comment: @Mello No problem! If you have any questions, feel free :)

Comment: I tried to google "how to hide sections html" without finding a result. What's the code to accomplish this? Javascript perhaps?

display: none;
That was the answer I was looking for, thanks!:D

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: It's for sure possible to subtitue html code with some other html, this i something you want to do with Javascript/jQuery. You CANT do this with CSS.

To solve your problem you should make 2 elements, one normal menu and one select element. Then show and hide them depending on screen size, take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/77khhzpx/

```
@media (max-width:400px){
    section#box1, section#box2{
        float: none;
        width:100%; 
    }
    #menu {
        display:none;
    }
    #mobile-menu{
        display:block;
    }
}
```